# loading image paths to create components with images ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSON that is providing a source prop to a component that would use it to create an `<img src={source} ... />` element. I have seen on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610659/reactjs-local-image-not-loading) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334874/load-images-based-on-dynamic-path-in-reactjs) that I need to import the picture with template literals to use it, `` <img src={require(`${source}`)} alt={title}/> `` where source is a prop, title is a prop.

The code is pasted below for reference.
Thank you for your patience and assistance!

***app.js***

```
  parseJson(){
   var data = require('./highlights.json');
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    console.log("source: " + obj.src);
  }
   return data.map((obj, key) =>
    <Highlight source={obj.source} link={obj.href} title={obj.title} desc={obj.desc} key={obj.src}/>  // returns the components and passes in the appropriate props
     )
 }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Menubar/>
      <div>
      <Profilepic onClick={this.toggleModal}/>
      </div>
      <div className = "HighlightsContainer">
      {this.parseJson()} // returns a bunch of components here
      </div>
      <UploadButton/>
      <UploadWindow show={this.state.uploadWindowOpen}/>

      <Modal show={this.state.isOpen}
      onClose={this.toggleModal}>
      <Signup/>
      </Modal>
      <PhotoViewer show={this.state.photoViewerOn}/>
      </div>
      );
  }
```

***highlight.jsx***

```
import React from 'react';
let Highlight = function statelessFunctionComponentClass(props) {
// the 4 props that are passed in 
  let source = props.source;
  let link = props.link;
  let title = props.title;
  let desc = props.desc;

  let style = {
    position: 'relative',
    width: '300px',
    height: '300px',
    background: 'blue',
    display: 'inline-block'
  };
//returns the component of an image button
  return (
    <button style = {style}>
    <a href={link}>
//the require statement is giving issue, without it buttons are created
//without require, with it i get the error described below.
    <img src={require(`${source}`)} alt={title}/>
    </a>
    <div id="highlight1-title">{title}</div>
    <div id="highlight1-desc">{desc}</div>
    </button>
    );
};

export default Highlight;
```

**the error - this error was fixed by changing to obj.src**
Error: Cannot find module 'undefined'.

```
  16 | return (
  17 |   <button style = {style}>
  18 |   <a href={link}>
> 19 |   <img src={require(`${source}`)} alt={title}/>
  20 |   </a>
  21 |   <div id="highlight1-title">{title}</div>
  22 |   <div id="highlight1-desc">{desc}</div>
```

** new module error **

```
Error: Cannot find module 'highlights/1.jpg'.
statelessFunctionComponentClass
C:/Users/auser/Documents/.../src/Component/Highlight.jsx:19

  16 | return (
  17 |   <button style = {style}>
  18 |   <a href={link}>
> 19 |   <img src={require(`${source}`)} alt={title}/>
  20 |   </a>
  21 |   <div id="highlight1-title">{title}</div>
  22 |   <div id="highlight1-desc">{desc}</div>
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer, as some Googling did point to the require method. I havent used it in React, but I've only started a few months ago, so maybe it's a recent thing :)

Comment: sure, no problem! Was confused why the comment was gone. Have a good night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are other problems to your approach, but the reason you're getting this error is because of this line:

```
<Highlight source={obj.source} link={obj.href} title={obj.title} desc={obj.desc} key={obj.src}/>  // returns the components and passes in the appropriate props
```

You pass in `obj.source` as the value of the `source` prop, but from the code preceding it looks like you meant to put `obj.src`.

Comment: Thank you, Duncan! That's what I get for naming these things similar yet different. I am now running into a separate issue. (editing the main post)

Comment: also, do you mind elaborating a bit more about potential issues with this approach? I'm completely new to react and this is what I could come up with so far - your insight would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sure - it's mostly to do with `require()`. It's not really a command you can execute in a browser, it's an instruction to the compiler (e.g. webpack) to include a file into a larger application bundle. Trying to call `require()` with a variable means that webpack (or browserify, or whatever) can't work out which file you want, because the variable doesn't have a value until the program runs. (Note this isn't true if you're writing server-side code in NodeJS, but I suspect that's not what you're doing).

Comment: P.S. If `source` is a string, `\`${source}\`` is exactly the same as `source`, so the template literal thing isn't really helping you at all.

Comment: Thank you Duncan (re: template literal). But I will do some more reading about the problem with require() usage in this case.

Comment: for any learners coming to visit in the future, i ended up creating a public folder, and the images are now loading with <img src={source} ... /> where source is the prop being passed in from the parent (which is parsed from the JSON file). Until I eventually try my hand at nodeJS, this will do for now.